# How to interpret arg min in the the following equation?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, optimization

I am studying the following equation:

$\hat{s}_m(n) = \text{arg}\text{min}_{s_m(n)\in A_s}|\frac{\psi_m^H}{||\psi_m^H||^2}y_m(n)-s_m(n)|^2$----(1)

here $A_s$ is 1x$N$ vector of QPSK symbols, $s_m(n)$ belongs to $A_s$, $\psi_m$ is a random complex number, $y_m(n)$ is 1x$N$ vector and $n$ ranges from $1$ to $N$ and **I have all these values.**

My query is what does arg min is signifying in this equation (1).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you just asking what does argmin mean in general?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir.....I know argmin basic definition which is on wikipedia.....I want to understand it in the sense of this given equation....